# What is Plotinus' theory (of graduationism) that inspired Augustine about?

Tags: ontology, plato, christianity, plotinus, augustine

I want to know what Plotinus' gradualism is exactly about. I've heard in a lecture about Augustine being inspired by that theory, but can't seem to find anything about this. Is this gradualism just another name for Plotinus' theory of emanation (aka emanationism)?

Any help or clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing. Gradualism refers to gradual descent from the higher to the lower levels of being with the metaphors of emanation and dimming, see e.g. [Causation and Creation in Late Antiquity, p.47](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Causation_and_Creation_in_Late_Antiquity/Ewu0BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), "*sense perceptions here are dim intellections, but intellections there are clear sense perceptions*".